# Two vectors of equal magnitude have a resultant equal to either of them in magnitude. The angle between them is:

Tags: vectors

Let the two vectors be A and B.

|A|=|B| but not direction is equal is told in the Q. So , let us take two cases .

a) Direction is equal & b) Direction is not equal.

a) Let’s say both A and B vectors lie on the X axis. Then , so will their resultant. Therefore , angle by R between either of them is always = 0 degrees.

b) Let’s say A is pointing towards X axis and Y towards Y axis.  Direction of resultant is between the two vectors.

Angle between R with either A or B is always = 45 degrees.

According to me , the question is. incomplete.

But from a solution online , what they have done is that :

$R^2 = A^2 + B^2 + 2(A)(B)cos \theta$

Since |A|=|B| , then we get $\theta$ = 120 degree from here.

Comment: Maybe easier to visualize: when adding two vectors, you can make a triangle out of the vectors and the resultant vector. The question is essentially asking when this triangle is equilateral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, "b) Let’s say A is pointing towards X axis and Y towards Y axis. Direction of resultant is between the two vectors Angle between R with either A or B is always = 45 degrees".

Yes, the angle between resultant vector and either of the vectors will be $45°$ but the magnitude of Resultant vector in such a case will be $\sqrt{2}|\vec{A}|=\sqrt{2}|\vec{B}| \neq |\vec{A}|=|\vec{B}|$

When direction is same then the magnitude of resultant vector will be double of that of either of the vectors, therefore direction of the two vectors can't be same.

Comment: Ok. I didn’t think that.

Comment: So , there is always just 1 case possible.

Comment: @SrijanM.T Yes, of course only one case when the angle between the vectors of equal magnitude is $120°$

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot

Comment: Do we say either of the vectors A or B is equal to Vector of resultant or only magnitude ?

Comment: @SrijanM.T $|\vec A|=|\vec B|=|\vec R|$ , where $\vec R$ is the resultant of vectors $\vec A$ and $\vec B$. This was the given condition. $\vec A + \vec B= \vec R$ is what we know. $\vec R \neq \vec A \neq \vec B$ necessarily.

Comment: Ok. @AmanKushwaha